# Delete item from the Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to delete an item from the following list. But when I try to grab the key, it shows the user id key which is `NsShnb2enJcYEkfeE2fiSzbDc6O2`. But I want to grab the key of each post. For example, if the user clicks on the first item in the list, it should grab the key `KSGhFSZg....`

There are lots of answers to the similar questions but the structure of the database is quite different here.

[image]

Here is the code, I used.

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Note, FirebaseNoteViewHolder>(Note.class, R.layout.item_note, FirebaseNoteViewHolder.class, mRef) {
    @Override
    public void populateViewHolder(FirebaseNoteViewHolder noteMessageViewHolder, final Note noteMessage, final int position) {
        noteMessageViewHolder.setTitle(noteMessage.getTitle());
        noteMessageViewHolder.setUpdatedDate(DateFormat.getInstance().format(noteMessage.getDataModified()));

        noteMessageViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), noteMessage.getDataModified().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                databaseReference.orderByChild("dataModified").equalTo(noteMessage.getDataModified().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                        new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }


                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the parent key so you can try:

```
      databaseReference.orderByChild("dataModified").equalTo(noteMessage.getDataModified().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
          new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            int positionCount=0;
            for(DataSnapshot note : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                if(positionCount==position){
                   firebase.child("notes").child(key).child(note .getKey()).removeValue();
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), note.getKey(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
               positionCount++;
            }


      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
     });
```

Comment: What is lstOfertas.add(bid); doing?

Comment: Sorry copied code. I will edit that. Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

for getting your key you should to give full path to your request. In your case

```
databaseReference.child("notes" + "/" + yourUserId ).orderByChild("dataModified").equalTo(noteMessage.getDataModified().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                    new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```